# Logstash Plugin for data transfer from Cassandra to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, plugins, cassandra, logstash

I am looking to push data from Cassandra to EL Cluster and see that logstash is good option to accomplish the task.

However, there is no [input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html) for Logstash to accept data with Source as Cassandra.
I saw a [post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-jdbc-plugin-cassandra-driver-not-loaded-error/38210/11) on EL forum that recommends using cassandra-jdbc driver but the driver isn't working as expected.

How can I can transfer data to EL from my data source?

Comment: There was another suggestion here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/load-cassandra-data-into-elasticsearch/38590

Comment: https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra

Comment: Thanks undefined-variable.  Elassandra will require replacing cassandra cluster and I am not looking to replace the existing infrastrucutre